# Why response from my WCF Service is empty when I call it from javascript on phonegap android?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I've WCF Service that response with JSON. I want to get the JSON String from my WCF Service from my javascript on phonegap android. But when I call the WCF Service from my javascript, the response from WCF Service is empty. I've test to call this WCF Service and it works. Is my javascript wrong?

here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function displayText()
        {
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "http://10.80.3.73/webservice/Service1.svc/json/weeklyflash/id",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function () { 
                            alert("ERROR"); 
                        }
                    });

        }   
</script>
```

the alert message only shows `[object Object]` and when I try to track it with firebug the response is empty.

here is the JSON String from WCF Service:

```
{"GetReportIdResult":[{"bulan":"4","total":"1728","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"8796383"},{"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL","uang":"5863408410"},{"bulan":"4","total":"46008","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"234498301"},{"bulan":"4","total":"190369","type":"UHT","uang":"1367063805"},{"bulan":"4","total":"33507","type":"WHP","uang":"235653242"},{"bulan":"5","total":"4761","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"134877865"},{"bulan":"5","total":"648663","type":"ESL","uang":"6645764498"},{"bulan":"5","total":"49305","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"266817346"},{"bulan":"5","total":"245867","type":"UHT","uang":"1446787280"},{"bulan":"5","total":"47974","type":"WHP","uang":"631929807"},{"bulan":"6","total":"5762","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"293393832"},{"bulan":"6","total":"594942","type":"ESL","uang":"6088671790"},{"bulan":"6","total":"39457","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"221983181"},{"bulan":"6","total":"236803","type":"UHT","uang":"2219506085"},{"bulan":"6","total":"24853","type":"WHP","uang":"386175022"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use jquery and specify `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery de-serializes the json string into a javascript object at runtime before invoking your success callback.

The reason you see `[object object]`  : that is  the string representation of 
a javascript object.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation :) then how can I parse my JSON and show it on specific `<div>` ? well, I try change `dataType:'jsonp'` and the response shows the JSON string when I debug it from firebug. but the problem is the javascript can't parse it. why?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, exactly.  If you would like to just display the string form of the json object in a div, you can use the json2.js (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library and simply call `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: I mean I want to parse the JSON Object and add that objects to text value on div. but thanks for your info :)